Why JPA is adding fields of subclass when dealing with superclass? How to prevent that?
I want to use a SQL function to get length of a saved blob.
I use jpa, an enity and a repository for that.
My implementation looks more or less like this:
public interface UploadRepository extends CrudRepository<Upload, String> {

    /**
     *
     * @param serviceType 
     * @return
     */
    @Query(value = "SELECT GUID, SERVICE_TYPE, FILE_NAME, LENGTH(FILE_BLOB) as FILE_SIZE, STATUS, UPLOADED_AT, UPLOADED_BY_ID from UPLOAD c WHERE c.SERVICE_TYPE=?1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<UploadWithSize> findByServiceTypeWithSize(String serviceType);

...


@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "UPLOAD")
@ClassExtractor(UploadExtractor.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Upload {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "GUID", length = 32)
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String guid;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_TYPE", length = 3)
    private String serviceType;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "FILE_NAME", length = 255)
    private String fileName;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 1)
    private char status;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "FILE_BLOB", columnDefinition = "NBLOB NOT NULL", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
    @Lob
    private byte[] blob;
...
}

I derived a subclass which features additional column.
The idea is to set FILE_SIZE on queries, but of course not to have such a column when saving.
@Entity
public class UploadWithSize extends Upload{

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "FILE_SIZE")
    private int fileSize;

    public void setFileSize(int fs) {
        this.fileSize = fs;
    }
   
    @Override
    public int getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }
}

I already found out that JPA per default will add a column DTYPE to my native query, to differentiate which class to use. That resulted in an exception. So I add a ClassExtractor.
public class UploadExtractor extends org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassExtractor {

    @Override
    public <T> Class<T> extractClassFromRow(DataRecord databaseRow, Session session) {
        if (databaseRow.containsKey("FILE_SIZE")) {
            return (Class<T>) UploadWithSize.class;
        } else {
            return (Class<T>) Upload.class;
        }
    }
}

My native queries work now with the repository!
BUT:
When I do something like...
Upload someUpload = new Upload();
repository.save(someUpload );

I get an Exception:
Internal Exception: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: FILE_SIZE: line 1 col 136 (at pos 135)
Error Code: 260
Call: SELECT GUID, FILE_BLOB, FILE_NAME, SERVICE_TYPE, STATUS, UPLOADED_AT, UPLOADED_BY_ID, FILE_SIZE FROM UPLOAD WHERE (GUID = ?)
    bind => [C91826D71B8A4723BAFD71DB0D5C48B1]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=CpsExtension )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2048)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:311)

This is not intuitive for me, on save the classextractor isn't used, how come FILE_SIZE is added? How to prevent that?
Or am I doing a completely overkill approach and there is a much simpler way to assign LENGTH result to a field?

With Hibernate I would use @Formula Annotation for this case. But u use eclipseLink
so I think this should work:
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "FILE_SIZE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int fileSize;
...


and you have to remove Annotation @MappedSuperclass, if your Upload is also Entity

Thank you! maybe there are more annotation I am not aware of. Unfortunately this didn't help I still got on repository.save():
Internal Exception: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: FILE_SIZE: line 1 col 85 (at pos 84) Error Code: 260 Call: SELECT GUID, ACTIVATION_CHANGED_AT, ACTIVATION_CHANGED_BY_ID, FILE_BLOB, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, SERVICE_TYPE, STATUS, UPLOADED_AT, UPLOADED_BY_ID FROM UPLOAD WHERE (GUID = ?)  bind => [43350420E6734C6C92C563CEA4FEB441] Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=Upload) 

I also tried to have my Entity without FILE_SIZE, but to use a List as return value.
@Query(value = "SELECT GUID, SERVICE_TYPE, FILE_NAME, LENGTH(FILE_BLOB) as FILE_SIZE  from UPLOAD c WHERE c.SERVICE_TYPE=?1", nativeQuery = true) List<Map<String, Object>> findByServiceTypeWithSize(String serviceType); 
But that results in
JpaSystemException: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.3.v202405220658): QueryException Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [interface jakarta.persistence.Tuple]. Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Tuple

@Column and @Transient is also invalid combination of Annotations unfortunaltely, LOL
